# Lagrange method for inequality

Tags: calculus, optimization

i have one question and any hint would be very helpful for me,we know how Lagrange multiplier works  ,for example  consider following problem

Example 2  Find the maximum and minimum of  subject to the constraint .

$f(x,y)=5*x-3*y$

constraint   $x^2+y^2=136$

and Lagrange use following methods

[image]

where The constant,$\lambda$ , is called the Lagrange Multiplier.

in our case

$f(x,y)=5*x-3*y$
and $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2=136$

and  triangular  form describes partial derivatives,but my question is:can we describe  this method for inequality? and if not what is reason? in inequality i meant

$g(x,y)<16$ or $g(x,y)>16$  or in our case $x^2+y^2<16$? or $x^2+y^2>16$

i dont remember if this case also works for Lagrange,but any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it still does apply but you must introduce slack variables in order to transform inequality constraints into equality constraints.

Seraching a little, I found one paper which looks good and totally appropriate for your question 
http://www.trin.cam.ac.uk/dpk10/IB/notes1.pdf

I also found a huge document of this topic
http://www.mit.edu/~dimitrib/Constrained-Opt.pdf

Comment: by the way second link does not work

Comment: @datodatuashvili.It works but took a long time to load (450 pages)

Comment: i have downloaded at home,i was outside of  home where it is blocked to download big files

Answer (score 2):

In those cases you can see that the sets that you describe with the inequalities are open sets (in case $g$ is continuous) and then you have to look for points $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (for the general case) such that $\nabla f(x)=0$ and $g(x)<a$ (or $g(x)>a$) for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and then determine by some method whether they are an extrema or not and which kind of extrema they are.